# Recyclerview dentro de otro recyclerview

Tags: android

He realizado un Recyclerview dentro de otro recyclerview (los dos cargan la lista de firebase), es algo asi como ver los alumnos de un IES (recyclerview en vertical) y dentro de este las asignaturas que cursan cada alumnos (recyclerview en horizontal).

```
Funciona funciona pero cuando las listas son largas va muy atascado.

 Ahi otra manera de implementar esto.
```

Gracias

Comment: Esta pregunta ya fue respondida, te dejo [el enlace.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36408266/create-a-recyclerview-with-both-horizontal-and-vertical-scrolling)

Comment: Agrega el código de lo que estas realizando por favor, revisar [ask],saludos